# get values of array within array json in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I need to get the values of the array "q1" which in array "questions", the arrays is json, and i need the values in java android.

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "q1": [
                "what my name?",
                "a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "Mac"
            ],
            "q2": [
                "what my age?",
                "1",
                "34",
                "80",
                "3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should show the effort you put in. We are not here to spoon feed you

Comment: Are you asking how to parse json using Java? What have you tried?

Comment: Look at the documentation on the existing json frameworks? Good place to start.

Comment: I tried a lot of very but i could not understand how to do that, I can to get values from one array but array within array i could not do it. and yes, in java

Answer (score 1):

Here I am answering your question to solve your problem but My friend you need to study first about json parsing.

**Suggestion :**
You can find example of it here :

http://primalpappachan.com/android/2010/06/05/parsing-json-in-android/

**Answer :**

```
JSONObject jresonseobj = response.getjObj();
JSONObject jobj;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jresonseobj.getString("questions"));

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
{
        jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // parse inner json here.  
}
```